function round(double precision, integer) does not exist (LINE: 4)
I am trying to write a query on datalemur but my solution is not getting accepted
Throwing me error : function round(double precision, integer) does not exist (LINE: 4)
Question : Link


My query not accepted :
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submit_date) AS mth,
    product_id                      AS product,
    round((AVG(stars)),
          2)                        AS avg_stars
FROM
    reviews
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submit_date),
    product_id
ORDER BY
    mth,
    product;

What is the mistake I am making could you help me to identify it.

so oracle or postgres?

Please do NOT post images of tables or code - give us a fiddle instead and copy and paste text into your questions instead!

@Verace : Ok sure next time onwards will post details

You have to CAST the integer to numeric
  SELECT
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submit_date) AS mth,
        product_id                      AS product,
        round(AVG(stars) ::numeric,2)
                                    avg_stars
    FROM
        reviews
    GROUP BY
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submit_date),
        product_id
    ORDER BY
        mth,
        product;

I think there is a problem with thier submit button,when i give answer with out round also i am getting the same error
        SELECT
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submit_date) AS mth,
            product_id                      AS product,
           avg(stars)::numeric(30,2)
                                        avg_stars
        FROM
            reviews
        GROUP BY
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submit_date),
            product_id
        ORDER BY
            mth,
            product;


Answer is not accepted same error.
